# Display an Image in DetailViewController Sent by MasterViewController using Apple SplitView Template

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ipad, master-detail

i'm working on an application and i'm still a beginner with ios programing.

I'm asking for your help because i used the apple MasterDetailView template.
I'm generating a list of file stored in my application, which i display within my MasterView(TableView).

When i click on one of the files contained in my list i generate an image in relationship with this file and i would like to display it in my DetailView.

Is there a solution to do it without destroying all my application :)

Thanks for you help guys!!

This is my Delegate and how my controllers are declared:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's your master controller that's responsible for creating the image....  You would normally create a property in your detail controller to hold a reference to the image. Inside the method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` of the master, you would pass that reference to the detail view controller.

(Alternatively, pass the file information instead and let the detail controller create the image.)

Comment: Thank you it's what i've tried and it seems to work perfectly!

Comment: @Bobyblanco: welcome to SO. Since Phillips's answer correctly answered your question you really should accept it. Please take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work